# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:xxx:

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on .net web api.....

> Web Api Config :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Verb Routing 
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "SmallBizApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new
                 {
                     id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                     action = RouteParameter.Optional
                 }
             );

            config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Insert(0, new SmallBiz.WebAPI.Common.JsonpFormatter());
        }
```

I am using jsonp format to load data in kendo-ui Gantt chart as can be seen...

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var projectdata = "http://localhost:1799/api",
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: projectdata + "/project",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: projectdata + "/project/put",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: projectdata + "/project/delete",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: projectdata + "/project/post",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProjectId",
                        fields: {
                            ProjectId: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                            Name: { validation: { required: true } },
                            Status: { validation: { required: true } },
                            IsActive: { type: "boolean" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            groupable: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "Name", title: "Project Name", width: "170px" },
                { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "110px" },
                { field: "IsActive", title: "Active", width: "50px" },
                { command: ["edit", "delete", "Setting","Task"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "150px" }
            ],
            editable: "popup"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller code :

```
public IQueryable<ProjectsDM> GetProject()
        {
            return db.Project;
        }
 [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult PutProjectsDM(int id, ProjectsDM projectsdm)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != projectsdm.ProjectId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(projectsdm).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                projectsdm.ModifiedBy = "adnan";
                projectsdm.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ProjectsDMExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

> Get method/action is working fine in kendo grid but i face problem
>   with put method/action(when we try to edit some record in grid)....

The errors in firebug .net tab

> **Response** :   "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the
>   request URI 'http://localhost:1799/api/project
>   /put?callback=jQuery191012879030621062526_1433486934717&models=[{\"ProjectId\":2%2C\"ClientId\":1%2C
>   \"FirmId\":1%2C\"Status\":\"Started\"%2C\"Name\":\"Flexi77\"%2C\"IsActive\":true%2C\"CreatedDate\":\"2015-06-03T00
>   :00:00\"%2C\"ModifiedDate\":\"2015-06-03T00:00:00\"%2C\"CreatedBy\":\"adnan\"%2C\"ModifiedBy\":\"adnan
>   \"}]&_=1433486934719'.", 
>   **>  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Project'
>   that matches the name 'put'."**
>
> json : "No action was found on the controller 'Project' that matches
>   the name 'put'."

Is there some route error or stupid mistake, please do help....
any kind of hint/help is much appreciated....
thanks for your time

Comment: try this url: projectdata + "/project/PutProjectsDM"

Comment: thanks for reply we checked but its not working...it is web api config problem i guess

Comment: Which method are you using for the request? Can you ensure it's PUT? You can use your browser's console (press F12).

Comment: @JotaBe yes i ensure its PUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your Web API action expects two parameters:

- `int id`, it's missing from the request URL
- `ProjectsDM projectsdm`, can be retrieved from the payload (request body)

You need to use an URL that includes the missing id parameter. In the route template it's optional, but, if it's missing, as the action which requires it, the action cannot be chosen by the action selector.

So either add the `id` to the URL, or remove the `id` parameter from the action.

Comment: i am passing id in url like, am i right?                                                             update: {
 url: projectdata + "/Project/Put/id",
 dataType: "jsonp"
  },

Comment: In the URL, you have to specify the action name, `PutProjectsDM`, not `Put`. The id in that position is correct